# How do I pad widgets in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I'll be quick.

Why is it that I can add padding to a root widget, but when I try to pad that root widget's child widgets it doesn't work?

Below, I pad the root widget in the kv file, which works.

py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


kivy.require('1.11.1')

class EntryScreen(GridLayout):

    pass




class PrimeApp(App):
    ''' Builds all of the screens as instances. '''
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.entry_screen = EntryScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Entry Screen')
        screen.add_widget(self.entry_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)


        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app = PrimeApp()
    main_app.run()
```

kivy example where I add padding to the root widget.

```
<EntryScreen>
    cols: 1
    spacing: 20
    size_hint_x: .5
    padding: [50,50,50,50]
    
        
    Button:
        text: 'New User'
    
    Button:
        text: 'Login'
            
    Button:
        text: 'Skip Login'
                
    Button:
        text: str(root.center_x)
```

Below, I try to pad the first button widget in the  widget, but it doesn't update and show any padding.

```
<EntryScreen>
    cols: 1
    #spacing: 20
    #size_hint_x: .5
    #padding: [50,50,50,50]
    
    GridLayout
        cols: 1
        
        Button:
            padding: [50,50]
            text: 'New User'
    
        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            
        Button:
            text: 'Skip Login'
                
        Button:
            text: str(root.center_x)
```

Also, when I try to make the padding for the button [50,50,50,50], I get an error where it states that the padding value is immutable, which is why I have it set to [50,50].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `padding` in a `Button` only takes a 2 value list. Trying to change it to a 4 value list will throw that error. Note that the `Button` padding adds space in the `Texture` of the `Button`, it does not add space around the `Button` (that would be the `padding` of the container of the `Button`). If the size of the `Button` is already bigger than needed for the specified `padding`, then the `padding` will have no effect.

Here is a modified version of your `kv` that will demonstrate the `padding` of a `Button`:

```
GridLayout
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    
    Button:
        padding: [50, 50]
        text: 'New User'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        
    Button:
        text: 'Skip Login'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
            
    Button:
        text: str(root.center_x)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```